# how does hydra manages timezone when it creates output directories?

Tags: python-3.6, fb-hydra

I have a .yaml configuration file which looks like:

```yaml
key: value

hydra:
  run:
    dir: ./data_fetcher/hydra_outputs/${now:%Y-%m-%d}/${now:%H-%M-%S}
```

with a python file `main.py`:

```py
import hydra

@hydra.main(config_path="data_fetcher/config", config_name="config")
def main(cfg: DictConfig):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When running `main.py` an output directory is created according to the current date and time.

How does Hydra get the current time ? is it possible to change the timezone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hydra is registering a simple OmegaConf custom resolver [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/blob/bc3567da6d06e9e0e437de4d4bddf9c0a9d23516/hydra/core/utils.py#L150) with a line like:

```py
register("now", lambda pattern: strftime(pattern, localtime()))
```

You can register your own custom resolver with a different name before `@hydra.main()` runs that will do what you want.

- Read about custom resolvers in the [OmegaConf documentation](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#custom-interpolations).
- Read about how to get time in a different time zone [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-current-time-in-different-timezone-using-python/?ref=lbp).

You can also file a feature request to add support for time zone to the `${now:...}` custom resolve in Hydra. a PR would be appreciated.
For example, `${now:...}` can support an optional second parameter for the time zone.

Comment: I made a PR here (which needs some improvements) https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/pull/1182